# How to get D-Link DWA-182 Rev. D1 running under Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, wifi-driver

I recently bought a D-Link DWA-182 Revision D1. The label says 'H/W Ver.:D1 F/W Ver.:4.00'. Unfortunately, the Linux Kernel does not ship the required driver. How can I get the wlan stick working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

D-Link provides a driver compatible with Linux 4.9 and older on its website:

https://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-182

There one can download the driver for Rev. D. In the archive there is a subfolder named "driver" which contains the code for the linux kernel module. Provided the necessary dependencies, the module can be compiled by invoking make. For convenience, I created a Github repository containing just the driver and brief build instructions:

https://github.com/MaxG87/DWA-182_Rev-D1

Unfortunately, the driver is not compatible with Kernel 4.16. I did not try any Kernel inbetween 4.9 and 4.16.

Update:

I patched out all the compile issues when using Linux 4.16. Using the master branch of the aforementioned GitHub repo, one can build a working kernel module. I did not perform extensive testing, but I am uploading this update using the DWA-182 on Linux 4.16. Many thanks to all the open source projects whose patches I used.

Comment: Hi Max, I know this is about a year old but just wanted to thank you again for making this available on your github.  I struggled for hours trying to find a compatible driver and was about to think mine was unsupported but finding your post saved me a lot of money and time! :D

Comment: I downloaded the driver source from https://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-182
the latest D version and compiled and installed it using 
`make`
and then installed using `make install`
after the reboot everything is working very well except that when I do any kernel related updates (even minor versions) I don't get my wifi detected and I need to repeat the compilation and installation again.

Does anyone know how to make this process automated each time I update the kernel?

Comment: You need to integrate your module to DKMS. Have a look at my deploy script at https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu/tree/5.6.1.6_35492.20191025_COEX20180928-6a6a. For more details you might create a question and ping me then.

Comment: It worked, I integrated my driver into DKMS using `deploy.sh` and `dkms.conf` from your repository, I starred it as it was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This hardware uses a RTL8812BU chipset, according to: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/D-Link_DWA-182_rev_D1

For this chipset, try the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y git
git clone https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu.git
cd rtl8822bu
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Comment: The question is about a DWA-182

Comment: @RalfFriedl My answer is about DWA-182 Revision D1; which has a chipset of RTL8822BU instead of the chipset that DWA 182 Revision C1 had which was RTL8812AU

Comment: Not sure this how hasn't received more votes. But this is the correct answer for  me with DWA-182-D1 on Ubuntu 18.04 - Kernel 5.0.0.32 generic

Comment: This works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Update for Ubtunu 18.04 on Kernel 4.15.0-60

https://github.com/MaxG87/DWA-182_Rev-D1 
fails

but
https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959

works like charm

Comment: Can you expand upon what this update actually does and how the OP would apply it? Please see [answer] and take our [tour].

Comment: Supporting Kernels that old is out of scope for me.  Currently I have to boot a kernel to test compilation. However, I would love to accept pull requests. Fixing stuff generally is quite easy, just `git log -S` for details of the compilation error message.

Answer (score -1):

Only solution that worked for me:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2472362

I used aircrack-ng